# Spock tests fail with NullPointerException once global GroovyMock was used polluting grails testing environment

Tags: grails, spock

I noticed sometimes my tests would fail after repeated runs. I realized that it happens once I use a `GroovyMock([global:true], SomeClass)`. The mocked classes no longer work in other Specification classes.

Example where a global mock can be setup:

```
@TestFor(EmploymentService)
class EmploymentServiceSpec extends Specification {

    Agreement agreement
    Member member

    def setup() {
        agreement = GroovyMock([global: true], Agreement)
        member = GroovyMock([global: true], Member)
    }

    def "some test"() {
    ...
    }
```

Other class where you need the real thing:

```
@TestFor(OtherService)
class OtherServiceSpec extends Specification {

    Agreement agreement
    Member member

    def setup() {
        agreement = new Agreement()
        member = new Member()
    }

    def "some test"() {
        member.someMethod() // would throw NPE here
    }
```

How can I turn off / clean up global mocks once I finished using them in a Specification?

Comment: Does marking the test with `@DirtiesRuntime` have an effect?

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem before posting the question. Posted the question together with the answer. I just shared it with the community here. I didn't try the @DirtiesRuntime, since the below works. Looking at the documentation, it sounds like it would work as well, but would cause the tests to run longer, because the same runtime wouldn't be reused as is the case when running tests fast over the grails terminal repeatedly. So I would stick to ConfineMetaClassChanges

Comment: "Actually, I solved the problem before posting the question." - I think you should accept your answer.

Comment: "it sounds like it would work as well, but would cause the tests to run longer" - It surprises me that `@DirtiesRuntime` actually takes longer at runtime than `@ConfineMetaClassChanges` but that is good info.  Will investigate.  Thank you!

Comment: There is a grace period of 2 days before one can accept their own answer after posting. I will do it, once SO will let me.

Comment: Global mocks are cleaned by Spock automatically `@ConfineMetaClassChanges` should not be necessary. Do you have parallel execution enabled? https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJyNUUtuwyAQ3XOK16xsqfIBImVRZZFNs-oJKB47qBgsGNJGUe7eMa5TRfWirBDvN2-wwxgiI43BfDRO-755G8nYzhrNNnillHE6JRxiCOfLUVgHF9612zvSPo-gLybfJjyorgpoqUOItrdeuyOx3hebHXx2Tv3gm0EAzAE2IVLiEKnF54k8-EToSHOOJBRJEyCPG1Q1Jn-gt2fy23JdC3qJUV9ebeJmWF5VIU_us-y3VHVnP6MvBbfgmKkuvGnWQVj_sue7_aPkafd3TKHdlmWYeaNVPbcTlORjVpqtZ09O4lW0y_kGX5WcaA

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, I think that your example does not reflect this issue well. This is about open issue [#445](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/445) and related to global mocks defined in `setup()`. I very slightly [modified your example](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&gist=59775801487dc267b4e24d7d21a829ef), see what it does.

Comment: @kriegaex your modification had several issues, double global mocking (really bad), capturing the variable after mocking instead of before. Here is a fixed version with mocking in setup https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJx1kD1uwzAMhXedgs1kA4UPECBDkCFLM-UErEw7QmVJoKi2QeG7l7Hz06LuJuA9fR_x3JAiC-QU7VvjMfTNMZF1nbMoLgZjrMecYc8xvp8PWtr7-Ip-5wlDSUCfQqHN8OvTlwFoqYPIrncB_YEEdxNmA6F4b675atAAZoHLwJQlMrXwcaIAciLoCKUwaUVtGpS0gqqGCx9UrU5ZT-8tM55fXJZmuLueNn8P0PJ4s2eSkqp6hi2dugCduo8tqnvlGfpplzUIF6p_euw81c2kFNLBF4T_GUczmm9_LY8A

Comment: I cannot see double global mocking. Please check again. The one line is commented out in order to mark where it was before my modification. It simply meant to illustrate the problem some people mean to have with global mocks created in setup methods. You are however totally right with your judgement that I did not capture the original meta class status at the correct time. That was just stupid, but the only issue, not one of several. BTW, can you maybe comment on #445? Is that a real issue? Should something be done there or it be closed? I only looked at it briefly.

Comment: You are right, while trying to make it pass I uncommented the line and it caused errors later, my bad. This question as well as #445 are mentioning grails, so I'd guess that there is some interaction between grails and spock that breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ConfineMetaClassChanges([Your, GloballyMocked, Classes])` on the method or class where you use global mocks to revert the global effect after usage.

More in [ConfineMetaClassChanges documentation](https://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/util/mop/ConfineMetaClassChanges.html)

Source:
One [blog](https://blog.bogdancarpean.com/grails-clean-global-mock-on-integration-tests-to-avoid-polluted-environment/) covered this, pointing to a [GitHub](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/445) discussion, where they pointed to using `@ConfineMetaClassChanges([%%MOCKED_CLASS%%])`.